# what are these values coming back from jruby? (File::Stat.dev_minor)

Tags: jruby

I have an app that uses jruby, and its been recording some information about files in a table. eg file size and major and minor device number. `File::Stat.dev_minor` and `File::Stat.dev_major`

However I have noticed that jruby is producing very different values that the native package ruby 1.9.2 for example under ruby;

```
irb(main):006:0> puts File::stat("/etc/passwd").dev_minor
5      <------- need to find this
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> puts File::stat("/etc/passwd").dev_major
104         <------- need to find this
=> nil
```

under jruby 1.6.4, this produces ClassNotFoundExceptions, however its also been returning a number which this app has been recording, and which I now need to convert back to native ruby.

```
# File.stat("/etc/passwd").dev_minor

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rubygems.defaults.OperatingSystemService
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Metho

Exception `LoadError' at file:/srv/logstash/logstash-monolithic-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/Win32API.rb:2 - Win32API only supported on win32
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rubygems.defaults.JrubyNativeService
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

26629      


# File.stat("/etc/passwd").dev_major

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rubygems.defaults.OperatingSystemService
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
Exception `LoadError' at file:/srv/logstash/logstash-monolithic-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/Win32API.rb:2 - Win32API only supported on win32
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rubygems.defaults.JrubyNativeService


0   <------- and this one too...
```

I am using jruby 1.6.4 using the sun java hotspot client 1.6.0_30 than from basic Ruby 1.9.2 on fedora.

Any suggestions?

I would like to convert those numbers back to the normal ruby format..

jruby -> File.stat("/etc/passwd").dev_minor seems to correspond to the values for `stat -c %d /etc/passwd` = 26629

Answer (score 1):

This is because `dev_minor` and `dev_major` only make sense for device files.  When using the `stat` function on device files, MRI and JRuby (which internally uses jnr-posix) behave the same:

```
sebastien@greystones:$ rvm use jruby-1.6-head
Using /home/sebastien/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6-head
sebastien@greystones:$ jruby -e 'File.stat("/dev/tty0").dev_minor'
sebastien@greystones:$ jruby -e 'puts File.stat("/dev/tty0").dev_minor'
5
sebastien@greystones:$ jruby -e 'puts File.stat("/dev/tty0").dev_major'
0

sebastien@greystones:$ rvm use 1.9.3-p0
Using /home/sebastien/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
sebastien@greystones:$ ruby -e 'puts File.stat("/dev/tty0").dev_minor'
5
sebastien@greystones:$ ruby -e 'puts File.stat("/dev/tty0").dev_major'
0
```